# geoLocation enabling without page-refresh?

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

Currently, we have to refresh the web-page (actually `PhoneGap` app) if the GPS was off and (after notifying the user) then turned-on.

How can we update the `GeoLocation` status without the need to refresh the page/app ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use a setInterval to check for support every few seconds?

Comment: because the `geoLocation` doesn't seem to be updated without a full refresh, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't believe you are right. Do you have a simple one page example I can run to verify?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps someone else out. I had the same issues with trying to load the geoLocation over Google Maps API in a multi page phonegap+JQM app. A setInterval/setTimer did not work as well. The only way i got it to work was doing a complete refresh also, kinda makes the app look broken.

onDeviceReady did not work for me either as geolocation was not called within index.html file

My solution was not to try to call geolocation when the geolocation view/page loads. Instead insert a button to call the script:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getLocation();" data-role="button">Get My Location</a>
```

Then call the geolocation API with Javascript attached to getLocation()

```
  function getLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess ,onError,
      { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true } );
        var lat;
        var lng;
    }
```

Comment: Actually even this workaround is not foolproof. Seems geolocation does not want to fire the first time around either. I'm going to checkout phonegap forums.